# How can I get a treeview from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement a search function in a treeview.
So, I want to get the value to be retrieved in a new form.
But my code error with this message.
`System.NullReferenceException`

Form1.cs

```cs
public TreeView TreeView1
{
    get { return treeView1; }
    set { this.treeView1 = value; }
}
```

Form2.cs

```cs
public void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    label1.Text = form1.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
}
```

Comment: prolly you need instance of existing form - not create new one

Comment: It kind of a code smell accessing the tree of another form. Instead of accessing controls directly, create properties/method on the form which proxy the controls properties. This is because if you ever change the tree on that form, your whole application will break.

Comment: You must check if form1.TreeView1.SelectedNode is null. If the treeview hasn't a node selected, that property is null and you can set your label text to empty or 'none'.

Comment: @Victor this will not help in this scenario. OP is clearly creating a new instance which is not the same in which the item is selected.

Comment: @MongZhu It's true. I wasn't notice it.

Comment: i know answer for ur problem about replacing strings in XML - please create new topic, where u ask, what Regex expression u should write to replace concrete strings and i will solve ur problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();

    form1.TreeView1.AfterSelect += (sender1, e1) =>            
        label1.Text = e1.Node?.Text ?? string.Empty;
        
    form1.Show();
```

You need create and show the form. Then, we manage `AfterSelect` event of `TreeView` of the new created form to set the `Label` text.